# AngularJS Disable button on submit - re enable on error

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs

I am having a problem dynamically disabling a button.

My API sleeps for 2 seconds to simulate a super slow connection, and I expect to see the submit button disabled on submit, the re-enable itself.

HTML - Manually disabling the button works...

```
<button data-ng-disabled="false" data-ng-click="submit()">Schedule Appointment</button>
```

HTML - This doesn't work

```
<button data-ng-disabled="{{ isSaving }}" data-ng-click="submit()">Schedule Appointment</button>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('ScheduleController', function ($scope, $http, $window, $timeout)
{
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.isSaving = false;

    $scope.submit = function() {
        $scope.isSaving = true;
        console.log('Schedule Appointment Pressed, isSaving', $scope.isSaving);

        $http.post('/api/v1/schedule/', $scope.formData)
        .success(function(data) {
             // Do Stuff
        })
        .error(function(data){
            $scope.isSaving = false;
            console.log('Error, isSaving', $scope.isSaving);
            $scope.errors = data.errors;
        });
    }   
});
```

Everything works perfectly, and the console.log outputs isSaving correctly. The problem is that the button doesn't actually get disabled unless i hardcode ng-disabled="true" into the html.

Comment: try to replace `data-ng-disabled="{{ isSaving }}"` with `data-ng-disabled="isSaving"`

Comment: @BogdanSavluk - That easy huh!!! It works... thank you so much! How am I supposed to know when I need to use `{{ }}` and when I am not to use it?

Comment: It depends on required argument type, in case of `ng-disabled` it is expression which would be evaluated on scope. For example, directive `ng-href`, requires template which would be interpolated using scope in this case argument can be any string, probably with `{{}}`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your HTML. 
You do not need {{}} while accessing scope variables in  ng directives.

```
<button ng-disabled="isSaving" ng-click="submit()">Schedule Appointment</button>
```

Hope it helps.